# Linear Congruential Generator has toggling lowest bit?

Tags: random

I am learning about linear congruential generators and read [a page at the Lawrence Livermore web site](https://nuclear.llnl.gov/CNP/rng/rngman/node4.html) about it. It says the following is a good LCG random number generator:

$$
x[n] = a x[n - 1] + b   (mod2^{64}), a = 2862933555777941757, b = 303700049
$$

What I see here is that whatever the seed is, it gets multiplied by an odd number, and then another odd number added to it. That makes the result toggle between even and odd, i.e. the lowest bit toggles between 0 and 1. Tried this in Python and confirmed it.

What makes this a *good* random number generator, as the page says, then?